# В цикле выводить только изменившееся значение

Tags: java, парсер, циклы, selenium

Есть цикл который через Selenium парсит строку в бесконечном цикле. Нужно чтоб при каждом изменении строки, она печаталась в консоль.[image: 1 число 2 второе чилсо]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float temp = новое значение;
if (temp != старое значение) {
     старое значение = temp;
     System.OutPrintLn(temp)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте переменную, в которую вы "положите" значение и каждую интеграцию сравнивайте. Если значение отличается от предыдущего, вводите его. К сожалению не могу описать это кодом (давно не работал с java).  Но что-то подобное:

```
int x =0
If(str!=x){System.OutPrintLn(x);}
```